# Proper Way to handle Multiple Mutations with React Immutability Helpers

Tags: reactjs, react-native, immutability

I'm trying to alter state using React's Immutability helpers for efficiency's sake, and everything seems to be fine.  My issue is I'd like to do both a `$splice` and a `$merge` on certain arrays in one go, and I'm not sure how.

It appears that:

```
var newState = React.addons.update(this.state, 
  cards: {$splice: [[0, 1]]},
  cards: {$push: this.pickNextCards(1)}
});
setState(newState);
```

won't work, and I've tried some variants which also appear not to work (second command always overrides the first).  I'm assuming (?) that this must be done in two steps.

What is the 'best practice' way to do this for speed/readability?  Should I just be altering `newState` directly with my second operation?  Will that result in poor performance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
var newState = React.addons.update(this.state, 
  cards: {
    $splice: [[0, 1]],
    $push: this.pickNextCards(1) 
   }
});
```

I've made a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5w3asrj8/1/) with working example. Check it!